# Custom attribute to switch property serialization to NetDataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontractserializer, netdatacontractserializer

In .NET 3.5, I would like to create a custom attribute (say [NetDataMember]) that would switch the serialization behavior from `DataContractSerializer` to `NetDataContractSerializer`.

Basically, for a class `A` as illustrated below

```
[DataContract]
class A
{
  [DataMember]
  public int SimpleProperty { get; set; }

  [Transcient]
  public IBar ComplexProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to obtain a serializer that would behave like `DataContractSerializer` by default, but that would be overriden with `NetDataContractSerializer` for properties marked with `[NetDataMember]`.

Any idea how to design a serializer that would achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no "out-of-the-box" way in WCF to do this - but a lot of really smart people have already tackled that problem.

Check out Aaron Skonnard's [blog post on the NetDataContractSerializer](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/04/21/22284.aspx) in which he present a behavior you can put on your data contracts as an attribute:

```
[NetDataContractFormat]
```

on your service interface (for all methods) or on a single method will use the NetDataContractSerializer for that call. You need to define this per operation or service - not on your data contracts.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually, I can't manage to produce the override effect. I am applying the attribute, but the overriding behavior is never called at (de)serialization time. Am I missing some when instantiating the DCS?

Comment: When deserializing, in WCF, no constructor is ever called - that's a normal behavior.

Comment: But to see whether or not the NetDataContractSerializer is being used, you should look at the messages being sent around - either use the WcfTestClient.exe in your Visual Studio Common7/IDE directory, or use something like Fiddler to view the traffic

Comment: @Rabskatran: thanks for pointing out - yes, seems that blog post is gone - can't seem to find it anymore. Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) by Aaron Skonnard for explanations - but unfortunately, that doesn't include the `[NetDataContractFormat]` attribute code, sorry...

Comment: An archived version of the blog post is here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110814134219/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/04/21/22284.aspx